# VS Code - Close / Close "Next Problem" Box / Window

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I navigate problems using `Go to Next Problem` and `Go to Previous Problem`, the box/window remains after moving to a different line.  I can't for the life of me figure out how to clear/toggle these, since they do not seem to clear themselves. How do I get rid of these without having to use the mouse to click the `X`? As a side note, I'm using the Neovim extension.

In the screenshot below, I am no longer on the line and can't seem to clear the problem box.
[image]

Comment: does pressing `Esc` clear the Problem window?

Comment: It doesn't help.